# How to fix error in bash script on sqlite

Tags: bash, sqlite, scripting

There is a list of `list.txt` for example `111 222 333` and sqlite of the database on `/folder/$list/sqlite db`
On this script, everything works until the command is redirected to sqlite

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n\r'
for line in $(cat list.txt)
do
cd /folder/$list/
sqlite3 basename.sqlite<<"EOF"
UPDATE options SET option_value='$list' WHERE option_name='name'
EOF
done
```

An error occurs because the parameter inside the "EOF" is not transmitted.
How to pass a parameter inside the "EOF" command?

Comment: would you post full error here?

Comment: Error: incomplete SQL: UPDATE options SET option_value='$list' WHERE option_name='name'

Comment: I think you are actually sending the literal '$list' to the sqlite instead of the variable value. Can you try "$list" ?

Comment: @MatiasBarrios, the error was not lost

Answer (score 0):

How about adding semicolon `;` to the end of a statement?

Like,
`UPDATE options SET option_value='$list' WHERE option_name='name';`